# Cards declined because of authentication

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe to manage payments on my site and it works fine when I'm using dummy cards that don't require authentication but when I use them I get an error.

I'm using test version of stripe to do everything so I don't know are the errors occurring because of that or there is something else that is causing the cards to be declined.

```
@csrf_exempt
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=int(str(request.POST["am"])),
            currency='usd',
            description=str(request.POST['desc']),
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
       )
        return redirect("pay_app:completed")
```

Comment: This is the output I get: Request req_UCpFi7sEm1Sx6e: Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication.

Comment: The /v1/charges API(`stripe.Charge.create`) isn't compatible with collecting authentication. If you need to handle customers with cards that enforce 3D Secure and the upcoming European SCA regulations, you'd need to migrate to using [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart).